# SQL - enforce constraints between tables

Tags: sql

I want to model in SQL a visits of managers in Factories.

I have 4 constraints that I want to enforce:

1. In any visit, there is **at least** one manager that participate in this visit.
2. manager can visit in the same factory more that one time, but in diffrent days.
3. manager can visit many factory in the sane day.
4. one visit can occured in a factory, at the most.

I build the next 2 table:

```
visit-Factory(Name Factory, date, during, summary)
\\where Name Factory, date are PK

visit-manager(Name Factory, data, manager)
\\ where Name Factory, date, manager are pk
```

This enforce the 3 last, but the first is not enforced.

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: How do _you_ think this can be enforced?

Answer (score 0):

In a good normalized database design, you need to ensure minimum duplication of data.

In this light, take a look at your current design and see where you can remove such duplication.

I don't know if you have learned about entities and how to model them yet, but if you did, think about the different entities you need.

Comment: I think about it already. How I can remove duplication? As I know, 1-NF ask to remove records with multivalued. So I did it, and spilt the visit to 2 sperate tables. How can I reduce the duplication more then that?

Comment: @AdamSh - Think 2-NF and 3-NF. Also look at the names of your tables - anything _duplicated_ there?

Comment: But this duplicated is necessary (again, 1-NF). I identify visit by factory's name and the date of this visit. Are you imply that I need to join this 2 tables? Because I don't get it. Thanks.

Comment: @AdamSh - I mean you are _missing_ a table. **visit**-factory and **visit**-manager have a duplication there... perhaps that should be a third table?

Comment: It's fairly clear you have three entities.  Manager(user), visit, and factory.  Layout out those three entities and see which "has many" of the others.  For instance does 1 single visit "have many" factories?  Probably not.  So use this one guideline, go through all the 3x2x1 = 6 possible combinations of these three models and for each combination (the first, which I did above was visit have many factories) using the above logic. This will get you started.  Consider the other end of the arrow to be the 'belong to' end.  Ignore "many to many" rlationships for now.

Comment: As I understood, the only third table that we can create is (Name factory, date) - but it doesn't make sense. I will need them to identify the manager and the summery. More of that, As I understood, that table fullfil 2-NF, 3-NF.

Comment: @AdamSh - See the comment from Michael Durrant.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant: "visit" has many "manager". For that, I build the table: visit-manager(Name Factory, date, manager), where manager is also PK. So for one visit, I have many managers. As I understood, you and Oded imply that I need to split one of the table. But for one manager I have the Factory and the date, which are necessary.

Comment: @AdamSh - Michael even gave you the names of the needed entities.

Comment: @Oded I can't create identify to visit, if this is what you mean. visit is inditify as Name-Factory and date.

Comment: @AdamSh - No, a visit could be - `Name-Factory`, `Manager` and `date`. And if that's not the case, you may need 4 tables.

Comment: @oded: Sorry, but I don't understood all the clues. I think about it a lot before I ask this question, and I have a "conceptual mistake". I would be happy for further information.

Comment: @AdamSh - Your mistake is in how you are thinking about "visits".